# Centering an inline ul/li around center li element

Tags: html, css

I have to make a website for computer science at school and I have a problem with centering the menu bar. I want it to be centered around the menu button, but it puts the icon off-center the way I do it.

How can I center the entire menu around the central `li` element?

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: /*#C94421*/
  #353535;
  margin: 0;
  /* reset de standard marges van de body -> geen randen links en rechts naast .menuBar div */
  text-align: center;
}

.menuBar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menuBar img {
  text-align: center;
}

.menuBar ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 65px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.menuBar ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 100px;
}

.menuBar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  height: 550px;
  width: 60%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 4.5px double white;
  border-bottom: 4.5px double white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Homepagina </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="menuBar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#"> Over mij </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Hobbies </a> </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <img src="logoNaam.jpg"> </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Muziek </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Waarom informatica </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">

      hoi

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Rob If I'm reading the question correctly, I think he wants to flow the other `li` elements around the image, which is centered in the page.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister yeah exactly

Comment: I'm still not sure what it is you're asking... Maybe include some image of your desired results to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the changes in the code :

You have to add :

```
.menuBar ul{
padding-left: 0px;}
```

also relace this :

```
.menuBar ul li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 65px;
line-height: 70px;}
```

with

```
.menuBar ul li {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
padding-right: 15px;
line-height: 70px;}
```

Also remove `width: 100px;` from `.menuBar ul li a`

- Better to reduce the font size to get it well aligned in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

I got the image centered using a flexbox layout. The image is always in the exact center of the page, and the menu items flow to the left and right of the centered image.

I adjusted the font sizes and padding so that it shows up well in the demo. I also needed to change the `li` to `div` to get the menu to work semantically after the changes.

**Live Demo:**

```css
body {
    background-color: /*#C94421*/ #353535;
    margin: 0; /* reset de standard marges van de body -> geen randen links en rechts naast .menuBar div */
    text-align: center;
}

.menuBar {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}

.menuBar img {
    text-align: center;
}

.menuBar {
    display: flex;
}

.menuBar > div {
    display: block;
    line-height: 70px;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.left {
    text-align: right;
}

.right {
    text-align: left;
}

.menuBar > div > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.menuBar > div.central {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.menuBar > div a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100px;
}

.menuBar a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.jumbotron .container {
    height: 550px;
    width: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 4.5px double white;
    border-bottom: 4.5px double white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuBar">
            <div class="left"><div> <a href="#"> Over mij </a> </div>
                <div> <a href="#"> Hobbies </a> </div></div>
            <div class="central"> <a href="#"> <img src="logoNaam.jpg"> </a> </div>
                <div class="right">
            <div> <a href="#"> Muziek </a> </div>
            <div> <a href="#"> Waarom informatica </a> </div>
                </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

            hoi

        </div>
    </div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/2ejfdoc3/1/